# JLink function not producing result

Tags: java

I have a simple JLink function as follows:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
sha256Signature[bytesList_] :=
JavaBlock[
  Module[{sig, mdc, mdo},
  InstallJava[];
  mdc = LoadJavaClass["java.security.MessageDigest"];
  mdo = mdc.getInstance["SHA-256"];
  mdo[update[bytesList]];
  sig = mdo[digest];
  ReleaseJavaObject[mdo];
  Return[sig]
 ]
];
sha256Signature[byteList]
```

It produces the following output

```
(JLink`JavaClass["java.security.MessageDigest", 0, {JLink`JVM["vm1"]}, 1,
java`security`MessageDigest`", False, True].getInstance["SHA-256"])[digest]
```

There is no error indication, but the code doesn't seem to do anything. I  must be missing something simple.

Making suggested modifications (see below)

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
sha256Signature[bytesList_] :=
  JavaBlock[
   Module[{sig, mdc, mdo},
    mdc = LoadJavaClass["java.security.MessageDigest"];
    mdo = MessageDigest`getInstance["SHA-256"];
    mdo[update[bytesList]];
    sig = mdo[digest];
    ReleaseJavaObject[mdo];
    Return[sig]
  ]
];
sha256Signature[byteList]
```

Produces

```
Java::fldx: Attempting to set field named digest defined in class
java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate to an incorrect type of value:
    JavaObject[java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate]».
$Failed
```

Comment: Move InstallJava[] out of the function to just below Needs["JLink`"]; (and put a ; after both). Change mdc.getInstance to essageDigest`getInstance.  Now what is your value for byteList?

Comment: I don't see any definition for digest?

Comment: Digest is a member of the Java class MessageDigest

Comment: See above for the result

Comment: @JohnnyFever While `mdo[digest]` and `mdo@digest` are truly equivalent, the former notation is very confusing and it's not how J/Link was designed to be used.  Please use `mdo@digest`.  With this notation it immediately becomes clear that you forgot the function call brackets: `mdo@digest[]`.  This is visually analogous to `mdo.digest()` in Java, just replace `.` by `@` and `()` by `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
sha256Signature[bytesList_] := 
 JavaBlock@Module[{mdo}, 
   LoadJavaClass["java.security.MessageDigest"];
   mdo = MessageDigest`getInstance["SHA-256"];
   mdo@update[bytesList];
   mdo@digest[]
 ]

sha256Signature[Range[10]]

(* ==> {-56, 72, -31, 1, 63, -97, 4, -87, -42, 63, -92, 60, -25, -3, 74,
        -16, 53, 21, 44, 124, 102, -102, 74, 64, 75, 103, 16, 124, -18, 95,
         46, 78} *)
```

It's much clearer if you use `@` instead of `[ ... ]` because it (almost) directly corresponds to the `.` in Java.

You do not need to use `ReleaseJavaObject` if you are already using [`JavaBlock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JavaBlock.html).

You do not need to us an explicit `Return` at the end of the function in Mathematica.  Just don't suppress returning the value by using `;`.